# Como posso subtrair de um array com várias posições com um mesmo número em C?

Tags: c, array

A atividade pede que eu informe um número de vagões e depois pede para que eu atribua um peso para cada um deles. Calculo a média desses pesos e depois subtraio a média dos pesos de cada um deles para chegar a um peso comum.

Aqui é onde se informa o número dos vagões e dos seus respectivos pesos:

```
int boxCarsQuantity;
int readValue
int numberPosition = 0;
int arrayWeight[0];
int sum=0;
int average=0;

    printf("Insira a quantidade de vagões\n");
    scanf("%d",&boxCarsQuantity);
    for(int i = 0; i<boxCarsQuantity; i++)
    {
        printf("Insert the weight of a Boxcar\n");
        scanf("%d",&readValue);
        arrayWeight[numberPosition] = readValue;
        sum=sum+arrayWeight[numberPosition];
        numberPosition++;
}
```

Aqui eu calculo a média dos pesos dos vagões:

```
    average=sum/boxCarsQuantity;
```

E aqui é onde eu exibo a média, e é onde eu devo exibir o quanto eu devo subtrair de cada vagão para que se chegue a um peso comum entre os vagões:

```
    printf("A média é: %d\n",average);

    for(int e=0; e<boxCarsQuantity; e++)
    {
    printf("%d\n",arrayWeight[numberPosition2]-average);
    numberPosition2++;
    }
```

***Porém, a última parte não está executando corretamente, pois não estou sabendo subtrair as posições de um array. Como eu posso fazer isso?***

Comment: Para este problema tu vai ter de percorrer o array com um `for` e pegar o peso total do vagão e subtrair o `average`.

Comment: Seu array arrayWeight deve ser realmente declarado com 0 posições? Por qual razão você não utiliza a variável do for como índice de seu array?

Answer (score 2):

Como os comentários já disseram, seu array tem tamanho 0, não tem como armazenar valores nele. Você precisa definir o array com um tamanho grande o bastante para armazenar todos os valores, ou então definir o tamanho do array em tempo de execução com malloc.

```
int boxCarsQuantity;
int *arrayWeight;

printf("Insira a quantidade de vagões\n");
scanf("%d", &boxCarsQuantity);
arrayWeight = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * boxCarsQuantity);
```

Outras dicas: declare average como tipo double para obter resultados de divisões com ponto flutuante, e use o iterador do for para acessar as posições do array, não há razão para declarar numberPosition.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int boxCarsQuantity;
    int readValue;
    int *arrayWeight;
    int sum = 0;
    double average = 0;

    printf("Insira a quantidade de vagões\n");
    scanf("%d", &boxCarsQuantity);
    arrayWeight = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int) * boxCarsQuantity);

    for(int i = 0; i < boxCarsQuantity; i++)
    {
        printf("Insert the weight of a Boxcar\n");
        scanf("%d", &readValue);

        arrayWeight[i] = readValue;
        sum += arrayWeight[i];
    }

    average = (double) sum/boxCarsQuantity;
    printf("A média é: %.2f\n", average);

    for(int j = 0; j < boxCarsQuantity; j++)
    {
        printf("%.2f\n", arrayWeight[j] - average);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Não esqueça que para cada `malloc`, deve haver um `free`.

Comment: printf("Obrigado :D");